# Tracking if email was sent in another app

Tags: android

I am developing an app where the user can share via email (GMail app) or sms. Both methods will launch an external app that will do the work.

Since I am implementing tracking analytics that will be triggered when the email/SMS is sent, my question is how to send back or detect the status of sent email from GMail to my app. I know that it may sound like a stupid question, but I was wondering if this is possible.

Comment: How would you even know the structure of all variants of gmail apps, not to mention all the possible security risks you're introducing by doing things like this without knowing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Could you do something like StackOverflow does and add something into the URL (when I click "share" at the bottom of this question, it takes my user number on the end) so you know when someone navigates to that link after receiving the email/SMS?

Comment: @JeffBridgman Unfortunately it is not possible to do so at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to send back or detect the status of sent email from gmail to my app

There is no requirement for the user to send the email, let alone for any email app (Gmail or otherwise) to let you know if the email was sent.

If the email is being processed automatically on some server, the server could use GCM or similar techniques to send a message to the device and your app indicating that the email was received.

Comment: Yes that's true, but the problem is that the email is sent directly from the device.

Comment: @Helmi: So? Either the email is being sent to your account for your server, or it is not. If it is, your server can perhaps determine if the message was received. If you are sending to arbitrary parties, and you are using arbitrary apps for it, **it is none of your business** whether the user actually sends the message or not. If you think it *is* your business, send the email or SMS directly, rather than using a third party app.

Comment: thanks for help , i will send it directly from my app.